# JavaFX Changing scenes with different sizes

Tags: java, javafx

I tried creating a simple *password manager*, just for my personal project, I have come across a problem where I switch scenes, but it will maintain the primary scene size.

I followed this and created a project (Modular with Maven): https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij

I have tried putting `.sizeToScene()` on my start() on my `Main`, but it didn't work. Here is the code for my `Main`:

```
public class App extends Application {
    private static Scene scene;
    LoginPageAppData loginPageAppData = new LoginPageAppData();
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        scene = new Scene(loadFXML("Login"));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    static void setRoot(String fxml) throws IOException {
        scene.setRoot(loadFXML(fxml));
    }

    private static Parent loadFXML(String fxml) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource(fxml + ".fxml"));
        return fxmlLoader.load();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Here is my `Primary Controller` (I removed some code so I can show the important parts)

```
public class LoginPageController {
    App app = new App();

    @FXML
    private PasswordField passwordfield;

@FXML
    private void switchToMain() throws IOException {
        App.setRoot("MainPage");
    }

 @FXML
    void passwordpressed(KeyEvent event) throws IOException {
        if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {
            app.loginPageAppData.setUsername(getUsername());
            app.loginPageAppData.setPassword(getPassword());
            if (app.loginPageAppData.verifyUsername() == true && app.loginPageAppData.verifyPassword() == true) {
                switchToMain();
            } else System.out.println(false);
        }
    }
```

Here is with image example if you are confused:

Here is the primary scene:
[image: first scene]

Second scene: it should *not* look like this:
[image: wrong]

Second scene: it should look like this:
[image: right]

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and post a [mcve] (including the FXML files)? Remember that we don't have your icon images nor your database (if you are using one). Just post code that opens the main stage after closing the login stage.

Comment: What happens with `sizeToScene()`?

Comment: @Abra My bad i was trying to explain it well since some of my post were short and not that understandable so they just took it down

Comment: @trashgod i tried adding the `sizeToScene( )` on my `start( )` from all lines from it but it doesn't resize. people keep telling me "just keep the stage and just use `sizeToScene( )`

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear where your code is going awry.

Starting from this complete [`SceneSelector`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69978882/230513), note how each scene's size is defined in the corresponding `.fxml` file. This is done solely for demonstration: ordinarily, one would allow the scene to adopt the preferred size of its children.

To illustrate the effect, I updated the `changeScene()` method as shown below to enlarge (artificially) and center the selected view. Try altering one of the `.fxml` files and leaving the preferred sizes alone to see how it works

```
private void changeScene(…) throws IOException {
    Region region = FXMLLoader.load(…);
    …
    region.setPrefWidth(640);
    region.setPrefHeight(480);
    stage.sizeToScene();
    stage.centerOnScreen();
    stage.show();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok so if you have followed this one

> I followed this and created a project (Modular with Maven): https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij

and java will autogenerate some methods for you and one of those are `setRoot( )` that contains the following

```
static void setRoot(String fxml) throws IOException {
        scene.setRoot(loadFXML(fxml));
    }
```

Now Add the `scene.getWindow().sizeToScene();`

```
static void setRoot(String fxml) throws IOException {
        scene.setRoot(loadFXML(fxml));
        scene.getWindow().sizeToScene();
    }
```

@trashgod here you go :)

Comment: looks fishy - static scope is wrong always (there are corner cases, this is no one them;)

Comment: @kleopatra wait I'm currently learning but static var is bad/wrong?

Comment: @kleopatra is correct; without context, incorrectly using `static` could be _why_ you need `sizeToScene()`. As this does [_not_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72919375/javafx-changing-scenes-with-different-sizes?noredirect=1#comment128805402_72919375) solve your problem, please edit your question include a [mre] that reflects what you tried and exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: As you may have [identified the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73198948/when-switching-primary-stage-fxml-file-doesnt-resize-and-displays-distorted-vi?noredirect=1#comment129302150_73198948), you can update this answer.